# Klyachko-type inequalities for shifted Schur structure constants

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Klyachko (+Knutson-Tao) provide a set of inequalities that are necessary and sufficient for the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient $c^{\lambda}_{\mu\nu}$  to be non-zero.

Is there a similar result for the multiplicative constants for the **shifted Schur functions** (it is known that the corresponding Littlewood--Richardson coefficients generalize the classical ones)?